# Abstrat class for different realization?

Tags: typescript

There is abstarct class:

```
export abstract class Button {
  constructor(public config: IButton) {}
  abstract click();
}
```

And concret class:

```
class ButtonShowMap extends Button {
  private isShow = false;
  constructor(public config: IButton) {
    super(config);
  }

  click(interactive: InteractiveMap) {}
}
```

Why I can not rewrite method click in child classes:

```
click(interactive: InteractiveMap) {}
click(id: number) {}
```

So. I want to create concrete class based on Button and pass to click method a different parameters

Comment: So. I want to create concrete class based on Button and pass to click method a different parameters

Comment: Each concrete class can has click method with different number of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to `Button` you should be able to call `click()` without it causing any runtime issues. If your your code were allowed you could potentially  write something like below and cause a runtime error:

```
let b: Button = new ButtonShowMap({});
b.click() // runtime error ButtonShowMap was expecting a parameter here
```

You can potentially make `click` have an `any` parameter although calls on a base class reference will not be type safe (since you can pass in anything, while the implementation might expect a specific parameter type).

The type safe option to allow sub classes to add a parameter would be to use `never`, but that would mean you could not call `click` on a `Button` reference without some type assertions (which is probably fine since it would not be type safe anyway):

```
export abstract class Button {
  constructor(public config: IButton) {}
  abstract click(p: never): void;
}
class ButtonShowMap extends Button {
  private isShow = false;
  constructor(public config: IButton) {
    super(config);
  }

  click(interactive: InteractiveMap): void {}
}

let b: Button = new ButtonShowMap({});
b.click() // build time error you don't knwo what you need to call this with
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=78&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCAnAhgY2ASwG4QLIphQC8UA3lAPZQBcUAzsEpnAOZQC+AUKJLAEIBXYMEpwS5bhAAeYSkmBQUAI0aoMUNABsU9elCEix5LlE1i1gjPIAUYQcq2Y05uADNMrOjEOi4ASklTJVUmdEVtZwBrOzo4CFwkfzpsSkwAEwBuLm5tXX1fMQBlAAtKAHcCIhlEOHSC4T8TMzBmbBREKEx6UoqJNxQteghsszQLJitRJDsHJxdx909vQoDmswZBSBnFj1Z-Uc4uYMi0GJZEdSxcbwRkcJx8QmSoVIyg7i4tCEVlOlWJPFygZGsUypVCDYyBwDlxlAA6U4xQIAehRUGUgkwWnSUCwAFtoMgkPIoCBKIIoOkxAByRRRODlajlEodMkUqDxCC40SaQZaPElbpQcqYYAlKBAA)

Comment: Maybe I need to use pattern? Anyway my click method has own realization and depends by parameters